# For a question to be marked as a duplicate, the target question must have an answer? Why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-questions

Not long ago, a new user posted a question that was simple a link to an existing question. It seems that the user was having the same problem and wanted to draw attention to it.

This question appeared on the low quality review queue, and I thought the obvious action was to mark it as a duplicate of the original question that the user linked to. However, on trying to do this, a red message appears: "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer".

Why the restriction? Surely if two users ask an identical question, those questions are duplicates of each other regardless of whether they have answers or not.

If there is a good reason for this restriction, what should the correct course of action be in this case?

(The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059458/i-have-downloaded-the-gdb-7-6-source-code-i-want-to-compile-the-source-code-fo), if you're interested.)

Comment: Oh, the irony of this question being a duplicate...

Comment: `a question that was simple a link to an existing question` so it wasn't really a question, how is that a duplicate? You could have closed it for a dozen other reasons.